# differences of these two type of ajax syntax and use

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I first met Ajax, this snytax is always in my eye sight :

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

But today I come across with this :

I think this one is more flexible? I can work with jquery.. but why it did not require XMLHttpRequest like above?

```
$(function){
 $('#something').change(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'something.php',
      data: 'ip=' + $(something).val(),
      success: function(msg) {
      $('#result').html(msg);
      }
});
}
};
```

Comment: The top is vanilla js, the bottom uses jQuery. IMO, jQuery makes ajax **much** simpler and easier to write.

Comment: Of course jQuery uses `XMLHttpRequest`, but it tries to make things easier and hides it from you. That's what libraries usually do.

Comment: +1 for "When I first met Ajax", -1 for a confusing question though, overall 0

Comment: You should read about the jqXHR object

Comment: @JasonP: I wish people would stop using the term "vanilla js", it doesn't make it clear for those that are struggling with the concepts of javascript, and it's not like searching for the term makes it any clearer when the top result [is this](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is plain JavaScript. This is how an AJAX call is performed.

Your second example is jQuery. jQuery is simply providing a simpler, more readable way to make AJAX calls.

Underneath, the call is the same. jQuery just provides a cleaner way to access the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: so 2nd is the better choice? since my project is full of jquery usage..

Comment: @Violetta: Of course if you are *already* using jQuery, make full use of it!

Comment: @ViolettaMccullough If your project is already using jQuery, then you should use it for your AJAX calls as well, yes. It's easier to read and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The second option using jQuery is wrapper over first option. jQuery is basically the simple common cross browser wrapper for javascript functions.

Comment: *"cross browser wrapper for javascript functions"* Only for Ajax and DOM.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does use the XMLHttpRequest object. It just provides a nice interface over the top of it so you don't have to interact with it.